Impossible to access to PHPMyAdmin : failed to open
Although it did works fine 2 weeks ago, since this morning, after launched Uwamp (in no install mode), if i try to access to PHPMyAdmin, i got this error message :

( ! ) Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0


( ! ) Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/Users/pierr/OneDrive - alienor.org/Documents/Perso/Sauvegarde/Programmes portables/UwAmp/UwAmp/phpapps/phpmyadmin/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

I stopped firewall
I tried to define include_path on php_uwamp.ini but there is no "pear" folder on Uwamp
i tried to swap from PHP 5.6.18 to PHP 7.0.3
I downloaded the latest version of uwamp
Nothing helped...
Is this a known issue ? What did i miss ?
Thanks for your help.

Why does the question title say, "failed to open c:\php\pear" - that does not appear to be the error message you are actually getting. .../Programmes portables/UwAmp/UwAmp/phpapps/... - is it actually supposed to have UwAmp in there twice?

Hi, i change title of the post. And yes, .../Programmes portables/UwAmp/UwAmp/... is the right path.
I tried to download and launch an other instance of Uwamp a had the same issue, on an other path (on desktop).

And the file the error message mentions, actually exists?

The file C:/Users/pierr/OneDrive - alienor.org/Documents/Perso/Sauvegarde/Programmes portables/UwAmp/UwAmp/phpapps/phpmyadmin/index.php exists but not C:\php\pear ; there is no "php" folder in C: as there is no "pear" folder in the Uwamp directory C:\Users\pierr\OneDrive - alienor.org\Documents\Perso\Sauvegarde\Programmes portables\UwAmp\UwAmp\bin\php

include_path specifies a list of directories it will check for the file to include, but since your path is an absolute one, that shouldn't be relevant here to begin with. Plus, with . as the first path, it means it would search from the current directory first. Non-existing directories should not cause an error, but simply be skipped.

All include_path lines are commented on php.ini
Why, while it worked a few days ago, I now have this error without having changed anything?

Couldn't tell you, from the outside; although experience here teaches us, that less experienced users sometimes not realize that they changed something relevant :-) Maybe the fact that you apparently have this in a OneDrive-connected folder could play a role (and something changed in regard to that, perhaps?) You say you are running this in no-install mode, so I suppose it should be easy enough to copy the content elsewhere, outside the "influence" of OneDrive, and see if it behaves any different.

I do. As said before, i launched (from c:) a new fresh instance of Uwamp, just downloaded from https://www.uwamp.com/fr/ and launch it once uncompressed. But i got the same message ! So i think the problem is more Windows than Uwamp.
I do not understand why an instance thats ran perfectly 2 weeks ago now lead to an error.
And no, i do not change anything on settings.
